# Pact Testing in Spring Boot | Error in installing the au.com.dius.pact:consumer:4.6.1 in Intellij

Tags: java, spring-boot, intellij-idea, pact

I am trying to learn `Pact Testing` but I am having issue in installing `au.com.dius.pact:consumer:4.6.1` in `Intellij`.

I am using gradle for the build.

I am using this thing in the `build.gradle` file

```
implementation 'au.com.dius.pact.consumer:junit5:4.6.1'
```

I have tried with different versions but no luck. I am having hard time. It will be helpful if anyone can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is solved. Updating the gradle to 7.5+ solves the issue.